# rotateY and width relation in css3 and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently I am working on 3D gallery Gallery.

After working more than 2 days, I reached here

[image]

black lines means expect view. More better example is below

[image]

I just need to do 3D panoramic view. Where there can be n number of images which i need to put horizontally so that only 3 images much come in 1 column.

I am adding columns dynamically. but the problem is view.

Here is the code I have tried,

```
var maxAngle = 35, originalAngle = maxAngle, totalDivs = jQuery(".galleryWrapper").children(".container").length, increamentAngle = (maxAngle + maxAngle) / (totalDivs - 1), mainAngle = maxAngle;
            maxAngle = maxAngle + increamentAngle;

            for (var i = 1; i <= totalDivs; i++) {
                previousAngle = maxAngle;
                maxAngle = maxAngle - increamentAngle;
                var width = null, marginTop = null;
                if (!(1 == i || totalDivs == i)) {
                    var commonPercentage = mainAngle - Math.abs(maxAngle);
                    width = (130 - ((130 * commonPercentage) / 100)) * 1.07;
                    marginTop = commonPercentage * 1.05;

                } else {
                    width = 130;
                    marginTop = 0;
                }
                jQuery(".col" + i).css("margin-top", marginTop + "px");
                jQuery(".col" + i + " a").css("-o-transform", "rotateY(" + maxAngle + "deg)").css("-webkit-transform", "rotateY(" + maxAngle + "deg)").css("-moz-transform", "rotateY(" + maxAngle + "deg)").css("-ms-transform", "rotateY(" + maxAngle + "deg)").css("transform", "rotateY(" + maxAngle + "deg)");

                jQuery(".col" + i + " img").css("width", width + "px");
            }
```

What I have tried is, calculate the percentage, of mainAngle and Current angle. And according to that, I was calculating width. Similarity for margin top.

Is their any better way to solve this?

Comment: Could you add the related HTML and CSS to the question and create a demo of what you currently have please? This question is currently difficult to start looking at without all the relevant information. Not many people will spend time recreating your code to attempt a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going a little further in 3d transforms:

HTML

```
<div class="test">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div class="box">7</div>
<div class="box">8</div>
<div class="box">9</div>
<div class="box">10</div>
<div class="box">11</div>
<div class="box">12</div>
<div class="box">13</div>
<div class="box">14</div>
<div class="box">15</div>
<div class="box">16</div>
<div class="box">17</div>
<div class="box">18</div>
<div class="box">19</div>
<div class="box">20</div>
<div class="box">21</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 50%;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-y: 150px;
}


.box{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px 500px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.box:nth-child(3n+1) {
    top: 0px;
}
.box:nth-child(3n+2) {
    top: 110px;
}
.box:nth-child(3n+3) {
    top: 220px;
}

.box:nth-child(1), .box:nth-child(2), .box:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(42deg);
}
.box:nth-child(4), .box:nth-child(5), .box:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(28deg);
}
.box:nth-child(7), .box:nth-child(8), .box:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(14deg);
}
.box:nth-child(13), .box:nth-child(14), .box:nth-child(15) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-14deg);
}
.box:nth-child(16), .box:nth-child(17), .box:nth-child(18) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-28deg);
}
.box:nth-child(19), .box:nth-child(20), .box:nth-child(21) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-42deg);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VLqhg/1/)

Updated the demo with new width value for the container (as per comments below)

Comment: looks good.. tomorrow i will implement and then i will mark it as answer.

Just a question, in chrome i can see only 18 divs. what can be the reason for that?

Comment: the .test width is smaller than it should be, and the 19th div (and following) fell outside of the container. If you make the window wide  enough you will see them, but else the scrollbar that appears is sized only for the container width...  Just set .test { width:  1000px }

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are trying to make your slides look they are receding into 3D space, so each looks further and further away from the viewer. IMO a good choice would be:

```
transform: perspective(...)
```

You can use this to make an entire element and its contents rotate in a 3D space. Apply it to the parent div with rotateY and it will form a "wall" which looks further and further away as it gets wider.

Sample html:

```
<ul class="photos">
    <li>content</li>
    ...
    <li>content</li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
.photos {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(45deg);
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(45deg);
}
```

See [this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C23T7/1/) for a more full example.

Comment: looks close... but if you go through the second image, i need to make full 3d wall... its just a 50%.
there can be `n` number of columns. and needs to look same as 3d wall..